# Filterable inside custom select error using php created select menu "option value"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-mobile

I am building a website for my phone using JQuery mobile. I am using the "Filterable inside custom select" from the 1.4.5 demo.

It works when I manually add the option values in to the code.

```
<div class="ui-field-contain">
    <select id="filter-menu" data-native-menu="false" class="filterable-select">
        <option value="SFO">San Francisco</option>
        <option value="LAX">Los Angeles</option>
```

It works when I create one from a php file.

```
<div class="ui-field-contain">
  <select name="Position" id="Position" data-native-menu="false" class="filterable-select"  data-mini="true">
           <option value="<?php echo $PositionID ?>"><?php echo $position ?></option>
```

However when I populate more than one by looping them

```
foreach($getAllComp as $row)
{
   $PosID = $row["CompanyID"];
   $Pos = $row["Company"];
   $AllPositions .= "<option value=\"".$row['CompanyID']."">".$row['Company']."</option>\n  ";
}
```

by creating

```
<div class="ui-field-contain">
        <select name="Position" id="Position" data-native-menu="false" class="filterable-select"  data-mini="true">
                   <option value="<?php echo $PositionID ?>"><?php echo $position ?></option>
                <?php echo $AllPositions ?>
        </select>
```

I get the following error,
TypeError: listview is undefined

it refers to

```
form = listview.jqmData( "filter-form" )
```

[from the function supplied from the demo](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/selectmenu-custom-filter/#&ui-state=dialog)

When looking at the browsers inspection console it shows the php populating the "option values" perfectly as they are in the previous two attempts.

I have tried moving the function to different places on my page etc amongst a heap of other things. Maybe it just can't be done?
Thanks in advance.

The code is

```
( function( $ ) {
function pageIsSelectmenuDialog( page ) {
var isDialog = false,
    id = page && page.attr( "id" );
$( ".filterable-select" ).each( function() {
    if ( $( this ).attr( "id" ) + "-dialog" === id ) {
        isDialog = true;
        return false;
    }
});
return isDialog;
}
$.mobile.document.on( "selectmenucreate", ".filterable-select",     function( event ) {
    var input,
        selectmenu = $( event.target ),
        list = $( "#" + selectmenu.attr( "id" ) + "-menu" ),
        form = list.jqmData( "filter-form" );
            if ( !form ) {
        input = $( "<input data-type='search'></input>" );
        form = $( "<form></form>" ).append( input );
        input.textinput();
        list
            .before( form )
            .jqmData( "filter-form", form ) ;
        form.jqmData( "listview", list );
    }

    selectmenu
        .filterable({
            input: input,
            children: "> option[value]"
        })
         .on( "filterablefilter", function() {
            selectmenu.selectmenu( "refresh" );
        });
})
.on( "pagecontainerbeforeshow", function( event, data ) {
    var listview, form;
    if ( !pageIsSelectmenuDialog( data.toPage ) ) {
        return;
    }
    listview = data.toPage.find( "ul" );
    form = listview.jqmData( "filter-form" );
    data.toPage.jqmData( "listview", listview );
    listview.before( form );
})
.on( "pagecontainerhide", function( event, data ) {
    var listview, form;
    if ( !pageIsSelectmenuDialog( data.toPage ) ) {
        return;
    }
    listview = data.prevPage.jqmData( "listview" ),
    form = listview.jqmData( "filter-form" );
    listview.before( form );
});
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: You need to show us the full js code so we can explain why you do not have a reference to the element you want.

Comment: thanks @DavidSoussan for getting back to me. The error refers to the line fourth from the bottom.

Comment: I think this is broken on the JQM site. Changing the last occurence of this line: `listview = data.prevPage.jqmData( "listview" )` to `listview = data.toPage.jqmData( "listview" )` worked for me